# Getting a specific "element" from within an "element" when parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, parsing

I am working on parsing posts that my app is receiving from Wordpress. I am getting the data. And i am putting it in a dictionary. The only problem is that I am receiving 7 posts currently. Below is what I am getting from the server.

```
status": "ok",
"count": 7,
"count_total": 7,
"pages": 1,
"posts": [
{
  "id": 125,
  "type": "post",
  "slug": "michaela-hi",
  "url": "http:\/\/www.garytournaments.com\/2013\/06\/18\/michaela-hi\/",
  "status": "publish",
  "title": "Test Posts",
  so on and so on..till the next post
  "id": 117,
  "type": "post",
  "slug": "may-4th-tournament",
  "url": "http:\/\/www.garytournaments.com\/2013\/04\/29\/may-4th-tournament\/",
  "status": "publish",
  "title": "May 4th Tournament",
  "title_plain": "May 4th Tournament

  repeat;
```

My problem is that "id,slug,etc" is all in the value of post. I have no clue how to extract individual data as well break the data into indvidual posts

Comment: So posts is an array of dictionaries in your dictionary, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing some kind of looping like the below to process the posts information.

```
NSDictionary *myDict = ...; // from word press
NSArray *posts = [myDict objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *postDict in posts) {
    NSLog(@"post id: %@", [postDict objectForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for posts is an array of dictionary objects: each element of the array is a single post, the parts of which are broken into key-value pairs. Let me ask you something: are you using the Cocoa-Touch framework's support for parsing JSON? It will automatically convert the JSON data into NSArray and NSDictionary objects.

Comment: Im using the built in framework in xCode..So i assume it is the cocoa-touch